# if statement on a foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I notice i do this pattern a lot. Is there a better way to write this?

```
            bool hit=false;
            foreach (var tag in tags)
                if (tag == sz)
                {
                    hit = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (hit) continue;
            //tags.add(sz); or whatever i wanted to do
```

I know `if sz in tags` exist in other languages. I hope theres something in linq that can help?

Comment: linq could help. I don't know the exact syntax, but would be something like selectedTags = tags.Where(tag => tag != sz);

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Are you missing some curly braces? Even then it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mark, what is nonsensical about it?  I personally would have put in a few more braces, but this is a legal code fragment, provided that the code is found inside a loop, which is inside a method, property, event or indexer, which is in turn inside a type.

Comment: @Eric: The tag variable is out of scope at the point where he writes `//tags.add(tag); or whatever i wanted to do`, and even if it were in scope, that line would only be hit if sz *didn't* exist... perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @Mark: The divide divide operator makes @Eric right. The actual point is to understand how to exit the loop. Go upvote @Havard S's answer for constructively attacking the percieved problem you cite. (My actual point is tha the questioner has given good context in the question and is trying to illustrate a general idiom, so minor inconsistencies that most people on this thread would resolve in a flash arent as serious as to be characterised as "make no sense")

Comment: And why would you add the tag that doesn't match back into the same list you just found it from? Aargh... the more I try to make sense out of it, the less sense it makes. I guess I'm just reading too much into it - it was probably just a comment written without any thought. :-)

Comment: Yes, i accidentally use tag instead of sz. I had a more complicated class where tags is actually MediaTags and you had to write .title, i made it simpler without noticing that typo. Its fixed now.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Thanks for fixing the question. It probably wasn't necessary to do so because judging from the others' responses here I was probably the only person on here that couldn't understand it - how dumb am I :( ! Sorry for saying your question makes no sense. What I actually meant was something like 'that comment at the end of your code makes no sense - what are you trying to do?'. Now it makes sense to me after the edit.

Comment: @acidzombie24: and in the specific example in your question, you probably just want to use a set (or the closest equivalent depending on .NET version) instead of a list, then you don't need to check for existence before adding. :)

Comment: @Mark: It all makes sense to me now. :-)

Comment: @Eric: Yes, here too... it feels good! Sorry for the confusion earlier. I should have been clearer with my first comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the example:

```
if (tags.Contains(sz)) ...
```

For the more general problem:

```
if (tags.Any(tag => InvolvedLogic(tag))) ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `tags` is a `List<T>`:

```
if (tags.Contains(sz))
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Any `ICollection<T>` actually, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if a given item is in `tags`, do:

```
if(tags.Any(t => t == sz))
{
  // Do stuff here
}
```

If you want to grab a reference to the found item, do:

```
var foundTag = tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t == sz);
// foundTag is either the first tag matching the predicate,
//  or the default value of your tag type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tags.Any(t=>t == sz) == true)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Not as efficient as Any - this will walk all the items even when it's already got one.

Comment: Indeed; don't do this. If someone says "do you have any money?" you don't have to count the bills in your pocket to give an answer, you just need to see if there are any.

Comment: @NetSide: But it's a **very bad** alternative. Do you want people to compete to come up with the worst possible 'alternatives' ? I don't get your point.

Comment: I will never understand why people tend to compare logical value to true instead just writing if (condition) ...

Comment: @Matajon, the explanation is straightforward. I would guess that over 95% of the "if" statements a beginner programmer sees are of the form "if(TESTEXPRESSION CONDITIONALOPERATOR VALUE)" -- if(i == 10), if (j > 20), and so on. It is very natural to internalize that the "if pattern" always has an expression, an operator, and a value, even though that's not actually a requirement of the language. Most people do not program by learning the formal language spec; they start with a technique they already know and extend it; sometimes that entails writing code that is more verbose than necessary.